# Package/Endpoint/Controller Layer Exception Handling Design

Tags: spring-boot, exception, controller-advice

So here is my requirement to handle component/package-specific exceptions. for example for package A, BAD Request should return spring default bad request-response, but for package B it should return custom response.

Answer (score 2):

You can specify the handled controller by this way:

```
@ControllerAdvice(assignableTypes = {MyController.class})
public class CoreExceptionHandler {
 ....
 ....
 ....
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can specify the behaviour for specific exceptions thrown from your code using an `@ExceptionHandler`. Also, you can limit your exception handlers to specific packages:

```
@ControllerAdvice(package = "com.example.b")
public class PackageBErrorHandler {

    @ResponseStatus(BAD_REQUEST)
    @ExceptionHandler
    @ResponseBody
    public ErrorDto handleValidationError(ConstraintValidationException e) {
        return ...; //build your custom response here
    }
}
```