# Controller Advice for specific class/package

Tags: spring, spring-boot, controller-advice

I am trying to limit my Controller Advice handling to only a specific package's subpackages (preferably) or a list of specific classes (I will have to manually add all classes manually this way, so it's not nearly as good). How would I go about doing this? My current advice class is like this:

```
@RestControllerAdvice
@Slf4j
@AllArgsConstructor
public class ExceptionHandler {
        
    //This exception should run in the entire spring project
    @ExceptionHandler({ MissingRequestHeaderException.class, BindException.class})
    public final ResponseEntity<ErrorDTO> exceptionBindRequestHandler(Exception ex) {
         //.. do whatever
    }

    //This exception should be only run in subpackages of com.example.subpackage1.*, for example
    @ExceptionHandler({ ConnectException.class })
    public final ResponseEntity<ErrorDTO> connectExceptionHandler(Exception ex) {
        //do whatever
    }
}
```

How would I limit the scope of controller advice on the 2nd `@ExceptionHandler`? Thanks!

Comment: I believe you're looking for this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66935326/package-endpoint-controller-layer-exception-handling-design

Comment: Looks Great! TYSM!